# Openssl, Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: openssl

I'm using a wildcard certificate from Let'sencrypt and deployed to 3 servers (1 Nginx, 1 Azure Load Balancer and 1 Azure Application Gateway).
Web access works perfectly for all 3 sites.
I also have a C application which leverage openssl 1.0.2l to talk with each server using websocket and it works before today.

From today, suddenly, my C application can't connect via Websocket anymore and backend openssl lib always complain invalid certificate.
BTW, nothing has been changed on server sides from yesterday to today.

so, I use command:

```
openssl s_client -connect server.name.com:443 -status
```

to check status. Strange results are:

1) On Mac, Openssl 1.0.2l, it reports error 20

2) On Mac, Openssl 1.1.1b, it reports OK.

3) On Windows, Openssl 1.0.2l, it reports error 20

4) On Windows, Openssl 1.1.1b, it reports error 20.

No idea how to debug issue with it anymore after different tries.

it just appears issue today.

```
CONNECTED(0000018C)
depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.server.name
verify return:1
OCSP response: no response sent
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = *.server.name
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
---
```

appreciate for tips and help.